# GDAL warp not aligning two rasters perfectly

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, gdalwarp, alignment

I'm trying to align one raster to another using GDAL Warp. I've read that it's important to pick a reference image and use its extent coords, cell resolution and the `-tap` argument to force the second image to align.

I'm trying to match the higher res image to the one with the lower resolution.

[image]

```
gdalwarp -s_srs EPSG:32630 -t_srs EPSG:32630 -tr 0.25 0.25 -r near -te 511711.9928 
6328998.9708 514192.6233 6331359.4866 -of GTiff -tap <path-input> <path-output>
```

And then it comes out slightly off:

[image]

The dimensions of the reference image are 9923 x 9442 and the dimensions of the output image are 9924 x 9443. I want these to be the exact same, with the same cell resolution. They must overlap perfectly for conversion to numpy arrays later.

Is something obviously wrong?

I'm aware of the Align Raster tool in QGIS, but I want this done in GDAL so I can adapt it to a Python script.

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks within your posts.

Answer (score 2):

Note that in principle you cannot always get exactly the same extent for two rasters that are at different resolutions. Suppose one raster is at 2 meter resolution, and the second is at 3 m. And you force the final extent to be 7 meters. When you add the -`tap` option to `gdalwarp` then the final rasters are forced to have integer values for the min and max extents.

I would suggest to first reproject both rasters to the same CRS and same resolution, without specifying neither `-te`  nor `-tap`. Then just clip one to the extent of the other.

HTH